# Showing unbiased estimator

Tags: statistics

Let $D_θ, 0 ≤ θ ≤ 1$, be the discrete distribution with PMF. Consider:

$$
\hat{\theta}=\frac{7-(X_1+ X_2 +X_3)}6
$$

Show that it is unbiased; and does it satisfy $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}Var(\theta)=0$ ?

I know that I am supposed to find $E(\hat{\theta})$ but how is $(X_1+ X_2 +X_3)$ supposed to be handled?

Thank you.

Comment: Hint for your question: Use the linearity of expectation.

Comment: Your data are not enough to infer if your estimator is unbiased....unbiased for what?